# RSS feeds reader plugin for jQuery strips HTML from blog posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rss

I'm using the RSS feed reader here: http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/

My blog posts on my site that include iframes or other get stripped out by the Google Feeds API (or by the jQuery plug-in, but my guess is by Google). I need a way to prevent this so I can get the full content of the blog on my site.

I'm using a Blogger blog as the main content update tool for my website so my co-workers can update the site on their own.

Thanks

Comment: On your website, are you able to use PHP or another server-side language, or only JavaScript?

Comment: Both, but everything is just html/css/javascript right now.

Comment: You need to go directly to the RSS feed URL in your browser to determine whether the content is missing from the feed. If it is missing, you cannot use this RSS feed, and will have to obtain the content a different way.

Comment: It isn't. The content is in the feed, but it gets lost in translation.

Comment: Are you willing to post the URL to the feed?

Comment: http://ilsmhome.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss
In this case, the first (most recent) post has a flash object. I also tried with an iframe from soundclound instead, neither worked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13228/discussion-between-mark-eirich-and-maxghost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags are being removed by the Google Feeds API. I recommend that you use [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org) (a PHP class) on the server-side to fetch and process the feed. It can be configured to not strip out any HTML tags (see [here](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/strip_htmltags#don_t_strip_any_tags_not_recommended)), and the output can be fully customized.